# What is the common code reuse strategy in C

Tags: c, svn, embedded

**Context**: C language, 8 bit microprocessor

We have identified components which can be reused between projects (products). But I can not find which is the best infrastructure to handle the reusable components.

Two possibilities I found up to now:

- Static libraries
- Shared files in subversion

Comment: The apparent difference here - between source level sharing and object level sharing - isn't all that great.  That said, questions which ask which of alternatives is the best are generally not a good fit for the SO format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my company, we used both approaches at the same time:

- We do two checkouts: one for the project, the other for the library.
- When the project needs to be compiled (via `Makefile`), we compile the library first.
- The library is then linked as if it was a binary-only library.
- When we release a project, we check whether the other projects still compile against the new library.
- When we release a project, we tag the library along with the project.

This way you get the best of both worlds:

- common code is shared: all projects benefit from bug fixes and improvements
- source code is always fully available for understanding and debugging
- source code availability encourages library maintenance (fixings, improvements, and experiments)
- the library boundaries impose a more API-like approach: clearer interface and project embedding
- you can pass compile-time flags to the library to build a different flavors
- you can always go back in time if needed without library-vs-project mismatching hassles
- if you are in a hurry, you can put off the library check.

The only drawback to this approach is that developers have not know what they are doing.  If they modify the library, they should know that the change will impact on all projects.  But you are already using a version control system and, if you use branches and the communication within your team is good, there should be no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot. I just would like to know how do you manage the releases of the libraries? at the moment of the release you tag it? or you generate a binary that is stored somewhere?

Comment: There is something else I miss in your aproach. Devolus mention something very important in point 1 and point 2. How did you solve those problems?

Comment: I found an interesting thesis where they describe the aproaches used for separation of concerns with the preprocessor http://wwwiti.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/iti_db/publikationen/ps/10/diss_kaestner.pdf. They mention some interesting tools like http://wwwiti.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/iti_db/research/cide/

Answer (score 4):

Both shared libraries and shared source let you share the common code among projects. Libraries present a better of the two alternatives, so you should use them if they are available on your platform. This lets you guard the source of the library from inadvertent modifications, which could happen if the code from source control is changed locally.

The only problem with sharing code through libraries may be lack of support for source-level debugging of library code by some of the tools in your embedded tool chain (e.g. debuggers attached to in-circuit emulators). In this case reusing code through the source may be acceptable. If possible, you should guard the source from modification through the file system access controls.

Comment: The poster was talking about sharing individual source files, not shared libraries. ;)

Comment: @Devolus The OP mentions static libraries in the question, so I think libraries are OK.

Comment: actually sharing source modules like shown in some threads eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673767/svn-common-code-with-externals?rq=1

Comment: could it add some overhead in memory footprint when using a library?

Comment: @ojota84 Theoretically, it could, if you do not partition your libraries at the right granularity, and your tools are not good enough to eliminate unused code. I would try it both ways with your specific tools to see if there's a difference in the size of executable code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have reusable components, libraries are the way to go.

1. It's easier to maintain and you have a clear interface. It's also easier to incorporate into new projects.
2. You can easily do individual unit tests on library code
3. Lesser risk to copy and paste code.
4. Programmers are more aware that this code is shared when they have to use it from a library.

Comment: are there some pros for svn aproach? I have seen many questions where they use SVN for reusing code eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669628/svn-best-way-to-share-common-code-across-projects

Comment: I have worked in a company where they used a similar approach and it was horrible, because the code got seperated into different projects. This means we had to fix bugs over and over again in separate copies. I don't really see a point in doing this. A library is a clean separation, and if the library is really a library, with no dependencies going back and forth, then it's imo the cleanest and best option. And debugging is not a reason, because you can have the source accessible anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Several good arguments have been made for the library approach.

However, there's at least one good argument for re-building (perhaps from the *same* source repository) each time you build a dependent project, and that would be the ability to apply target- project- or development stage- unique compile settings to all of the code, including the shared portion.

Comment: Exactly, and those build options(precompiler logic) are a big feature of C. But should we get rid of them by using a static library or there are architectural strategies that can give us these ability you describe.